# Syntax error Powershell create list SharePoint

Tags: powershell

I have some syntax problem in my script, I have this error :

[image]

```
Unexpected token '
```

This is the code:

```
if ($bCreate_Lists)
{

CreateList $webURL 100 "CatMissions" "Catégories de mission" "Catégories de mission" "Catégorie"'
@()'
@()

CreateList $webURL 100 "DomainesEtudes" "Domaines d études" "Domaines d études" "Domaine d étude"'
@("AN,Anglais,Text","ESP,Espagnol,Text","POR,Portugais,Text","L1,Langue 1,Text","L2,Langue 2,Text")'
@('
    "Domaine d étude_1|Domaine d étude_1_EN|Domaine d étude_1_ESP|Domaine d étude_1_POR|Domaine d étude_1_L1|Domaine d étude_1_L2"'
    ,"Domaine d étude_2|Domaine d étude_2_EN|Domaine d étude_2_ESP|Domaine d étude_2_POR|Domaine d étude_2_L1|Domaine d étude_2_L2"'
    ,"Domaine d étude_3|Domaine d étude_3_EN|Domaine d étude_3_ESP|Domaine d étude_3_POR|Domaine d étude_3_L1|Domaine d étude_3_L2"'
    ,"Domaine d étude_4|Domaine d étude_4_EN|Domaine d étude_4_ESP|Domaine d étude_4_POR|Domaine d étude_4_L1|Domaine d étude_4_L2"'
    ,"Domaine d étude_5|Domaine d étude_5_EN|Domaine d étude_5_ESP|Domaine d étude_5_POR|Domaine d étude_5_L1|Domaine d étude_5_L2"'
)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Post the error and the code in the question please

Comment: If our answers have helped you, please mark an answer and optionally upvote the answers that have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably failing on `@()'`, since it has an unbalanced single quote. I suspect you're trying to wrap the long line, which requires the use of the back-tick <kbd>`</kbd> preceded by a space:

So instead of:

```
CreateList $webURL 100 "CatMissions" ... "Catégorie"'
@()'
```

Use:

```
CreateList $webURL 100 "CatMissions" ... "Catégorie" `
@() `
```

**Note:** The space before the <kbd>`</kbd> is important!

The <kbd>**`** ~</kbd> character usually sits on the upper left corner of the keyboard of a US keyboard layout.

[image]

Given the error message you posted is in French, I suspect you're using the French keyboard layout, the key you're looking for is probably the one highlighted here:

[image]

Note, by placing the `,` on the previous line, Powershell will know you want to wrap the line and you won't need to use the line-continuation marker on those lines:

```
CreateList $webURL 100 "DomainesEtudes" "Domaines d études" "Domaines d études" "Domaine d étude" `
@("AN,Anglais,Text","ESP,Espagnol,Text","POR,Portugais,Text","L1,Langue 1,Text","L2,Langue 2,Text") `
@(
    "Domaine d étude_1|Domaine d étude_1_EN|Domaine d étude_1_ESP|Domaine d étude_1_POR|Domaine d étude_1_L1|Domaine d étude_1_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_2|Domaine d étude_2_EN|Domaine d étude_2_ESP|Domaine d étude_2_POR|Domaine d étude_2_L1|Domaine d étude_2_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_3|Domaine d étude_3_EN|Domaine d étude_3_ESP|Domaine d étude_3_POR|Domaine d étude_3_L1|Domaine d étude_3_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_4|Domaine d étude_4_EN|Domaine d étude_4_ESP|Domaine d étude_4_POR|Domaine d étude_4_L1|Domaine d étude_4_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_5|Domaine d étude_5_EN|Domaine d étude_5_ESP|Domaine d étude_5_POR|Domaine d étude_5_L1|Domaine d étude_5_L2"
)
```

If you don't put the `,` on the previous line, you'll need to replace the `'` on all other instances as well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I avec the same problem => http://puu.sh/jErUm/a6155147fa.png
With => 
http://puu.sh/jErVc/d93dfb68c9.png

Comment: Updated the answer, make sure you catch all the training `'`'s. You can see the error in the syntaxhighlighting already, note that some of the `,`'s are yellow and others are pink. They should all be pink.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's best to avoid line continuation characters because they can be confusing. It's best just to use intermediate variables:

```
CreateList $webURL 100 "CatMissions" "Catégories de mission" "Catégories de mission" "Catégorie" @() @()

$list1 = @("AN,Anglais,Text","ESP,Espagnol,Text","POR,Portugais,Text","L1,Langue 1,Text","L2,Langue 2,Text")

$list2 = @(
    "Domaine d étude_1|Domaine d étude_1_EN|Domaine d étude_1_ESP|Domaine d étude_1_POR|Domaine d étude_1_L1|Domaine d étude_1_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_2|Domaine d étude_2_EN|Domaine d étude_2_ESP|Domaine d étude_2_POR|Domaine d étude_2_L1|Domaine d étude_2_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_3|Domaine d étude_3_EN|Domaine d étude_3_ESP|Domaine d étude_3_POR|Domaine d étude_3_L1|Domaine d étude_3_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_4|Domaine d étude_4_EN|Domaine d étude_4_ESP|Domaine d étude_4_POR|Domaine d étude_4_L1|Domaine d étude_4_L2",
    "Domaine d étude_5|Domaine d étude_5_EN|Domaine d étude_5_ESP|Domaine d étude_5_POR|Domaine d étude_5_L1|Domaine d étude_5_L2"
)

CreateList $webURL 100 "DomainesEtudes" "Domaines d études" "Domaines d études" "Domaine d étude" $list1 $list2
```

Comment: Agreed, though even here some things, like placing the comma at the start of the line, which a lot of SQL folks do, can cause the issue above. This doesn't prevent it, but makes the chances of it happening a lot smaller.